# Orbeon - performance in big form

Tags: performance, orbeon, formbuilder

We wonder if orbeon can handle such big form contained abaut 2500 fields related dependencies and external validators from web services and 1000 sessions(users). What are the technical requirements for this application (server or servers architecture)?

Comment: Are your 1000 users concurrent users?

Comment: Yes, but it`s overstated I think

Answer (score 1):

Some of our users have created forms with over 1000 fields but 2500 fields is starting to be a lot! We have observed up to 10 MB/user of memory usage on such large forms, so you can do the math.